# How to function call a pre-installed COMADDin?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am written macro in outlook to automatically call a pre-installed comaddin "report as spam" when message is dropped in a folder. However, I am not able to run that add-in from macro.

```
Dim addin As COMAddIn
Dim adxModule As Object

Set addin = Application.COMAddIns.Item("Report as Spam")
Set adxModule = addin.Object

Call adxModule
```

The result should run Report as Spam which will pop a message to click send or cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that only if that other addin wants to be called by exposing the the `COMAddin.Object` property (are you sure `adxModule` variable in your code abobe is not Nothing?).

If that case the syntax would be `adxModule.SomeMemberName argumentsList`. Your code above calls an object, which is invalid unless the object has a *default member* - you need to call a member of that object. Look in the *Object Browser* (F2) to see if the add-in is exposing any procedure you can invoke that way.

It's possible the add-in doesn't expose any such members, if it wasn't designed to have members exposed to VBA code.

Comment: There was no members exposed but I was able to use keyboard shortcuts to call the function..not idea but got the job done.